# Database Backup missing some data and columns after restore

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a very weird issue regarding backup/restore. On my server a I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express and the Management Studio.

I am taking backup using:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDb
TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\MyDb.BAK'
WITH INIT
```

And I am copying this backup to my Server B where I have Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Web Edition.

On Server B I am running,

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDb]
FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\MyDb.bak'
WITH 
   MOVE 'MyDb' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\MyDb.mdf', 
   MOVE 'MyDb_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\MyDb.ldf'
GO
```

But when I compare the databases between 2 servers then I found that lot of rows are missing and some columns are also missing. I have done this lot of times and keep trying but getting the same result.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the original database contains **more than just one** data file? Check with `SELECT * FROM sys.database_files` on your original database - is there just one file for `ROWS` and one for `LOG` ? Or does your database have multiple data files?

Comment: @marc_s There are two files one for rows and one for log.

Comment: And you're really comparing the source database that you've backed up and restored? Not a more recent version of that database?? This is quite odd.... backup&restore is the most reliable way to get data from one instance to another, and I can't fathom under what circumstances it would just "lose" data.....

Comment: We still unable to find the reason. Not sure the problem is with restore or backup. Yes I am comparing dbs

Comment: Does you backup have more than version of the database?  In SSMS if the data exists but it came from another server you have to tell it to overwrite. Try a restore in SSMS right click restore.

Comment: @Blam same issue. In the Version of SQL Server 2008 I am seeing pre-release. May be this is the issue.